# Can we set ValidatInput(false) for only one element?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

It's easy to set our action not to validate the input just hooking up the attribute like

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Signup(SignupModel model)
{
    ... 
}
```

But I was wondering, is there a way to only do this in just one form field? and not all of them in the actual `<form>`

or, I have to use this and then worry about encoding properly all other fields?

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* rely on `ValidateInput` to 'encode' your values. It doesn't encode values - it just rejects some values outright. And even if you use it, you *still must encode all your values* that are user-entered and displayed on the site in any way.

In fact, because of that - I've never used that validation myself. For example, if all I did was rely on that validation, people would not be able to enter some very basic things in forms like this one, such as trying to show example HTML.

But even the MSDN documentation and every book I've read said that the ASP.NET validation there does *not* protect you against every possible malicious input. So essentially, you can *not* rely on it to protect your users. You still must encode values you are displaying (and you should encode them only as you are displaying them, otherwise you'll end up with all sorts of display bugs where you've double-encoded things)

Comment: thing is that I need to accept html code in just one field of the form, and I'm not sure what path to take.

Comment: Don't use the 'validate' anywhere; regardless whether you use the built-in validation, you *still* have to encode the other fields anyway. But just make sure you are doing that encoding for those other fields.

Comment: so, if I use `ValidateInput(true)` I don't really need to encode all values, right?

Comment: Wrong. You should *always* encode the values. That's what I'm saying: Validating the input isn't all that useful because it can't guarantee that you don't need to encode values. So, since you likely have to encode anyway... *if you encode all the time*, you might as well not do the validation using that method since you need it off for one action.

Comment: Note that MVC3 enabled turning validation off per-action as you are looking for here. *But still*, you would want to encode values for display when they come from user input.

Answer (score 0):

Using MVC3 , the attribute can be applied to Model by specifying SkipRequestValidation.

Comment: the tag specifically says `asp.net-mvc-2`